Commodore 64 game top down tank on alien moon. Radioactive craters and repair stations for damage
I remember most of my C64 games' names except a few which maybe I was younger and/or it didn't have a box and manual to help remember it.

A joystick controlled a tank or  lunar surface.
Top down graphics, possibly only left, right, up, and down - no diagonal movement.
After taking damage stop at a repair facility then it became a side view, and I would have to do vigorous joystick motions to do repair. Each repair station IIRC had only finite repair units.
Driving over a radioactive crater (distinguished by a cool graphical shimmer) would damage or kill my tank.

That is all can remember!  I have no memory of who the enemy was, or what kind of projectiles, or what victory conditions were.

Lunar outpost
Most probably the game that you are referring to is Lunar Outpost (1984):

Radioactive craters

The small grey/white diamond shapes in the above screenshot are the radioactive craters that you refer to, see legend below:

Repair facilities
In addition to the legend above showing repair stations, this review from Your Commodore (June 1985) states (emphasis is mine):

... To survive you have some help. Power strips allow you to move without using your internal batteries, power stations to recharge, repair stations to rebuild, munitions buildings to re-arm and pulsars to jam the Zytron navigational computers.

Top and side views
While the navigation of the game was from a top view approach,

the ammo dumps, fuel dumps and fighting were shown with a side view, as you say.
Ammo dump (yellow)

Repair base (dark blue)

Fuel tanks (pale blue)

Attack mode

Other resources

Lunar Outpost: Instruction Manual
Lunar Outpost (C64) Streamed on Real Hardware

